# Is it possible to change a field type to in-corporate a text editor

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

While creating a personal campaign page, there are various fields with type text or textarea etc. Is it possible to insert text editor (to allow some formatting) on say a field of type Textarea. I tried altering the form and changing the field type to tinyMCE. Does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What fields specifically? Custom fields or core fields? Can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: It's a civicrm core field. e.g. Event Summary (Event) / Your Message field (Personal Campaign Page) etc.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you wrote?